# Instance member 'data' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart

I/m facing this issue. Can anyone assist? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a null safety. Just add '!' after data. Example `snapshot!.data!.[i].name`

Comment: it showing same error

Comment: did you write like that ? 'snapshot!.data!.[i].name'

Comment: There is 4 errors in your screen all of them are different errors. Which one did you mean?

Comment: return ListView.builder(itemCount: AsyncSnapshot.data.lenght, itemBuilder: (context, i) this line

Comment: Try this: return ListView.builder(itemCount: AsyncSnapshot!.data.length, itemBuilder: (context, i)

Comment: and lenght should be length

Comment: it was showing same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248014/discussion-between-babar-ali-and-korra).

Answer (score 0):

To complement KOrra's answer,
In line 44, you have AsyncSnaphot.data.lenght. It should be snapshot.data.length

Comment: when i try this snapshot.data.length it was showing error in length

Comment: Because length was misspelled. You had lenght not length.

Comment: i have write length but it was showing same error return ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data.length, itemBuilder: (context, i)

Comment: Ok. Does your getUserData() function has type? For instance, documentsnapshot?

Comment: https://ibb.co/r7FS35v